# Python: why print statements and subprocess.call() output are out of sync?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I am running the following piece of code (call it batch.py)

```
for config in keystoneConfig: 
    cmdlist = generate_cmd_list(config)
    print ' '.join(cmdlist)
    subprocess.call(cmdlist)
```

And redirecting the output of batch.py to another file. i.e.

> ./batch.py > output.txt

But I realize that all the output from `subprocess.call()` goes before the `print` statement. Why is the output out of sync?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python is block buffering its own output and not flushing it before `subprocess.call()`, because you redirected its output to a file instead of the console; you would need to force line buffering or disable buffering, or manually flush before the subprocess call.

Comment: how do I "flush" a print statement?

Answer (score 4):

Flush with `sys.stdout.flush()` after printing and before making the subprocess call.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, adding `flish=True` for `print` didn't work, but this did.